# How to parse string fragment between two others using "sed" or other linux terminal utilities?

Tags: android, linux, sed

I need to parse the passphrase using ssid like trigger from android file (data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf)(need root)  using android terminal utilities, which will calling in java function. fragment of file  looks like the next:

```
network={
    ssid="12345678"
    psk="87654321"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
```

I need to parse psk phrase. I am trying to use this:

```
sed -n '/ssid=""+ssid+""psk"/,/"key_mgmt/p'
```

but it can't work, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the first example file from https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/5-wpa_supplicant.conf/:

```
$ cat file
# allow frontend (e.g., wpa_cli) to be used by all users in 'wheel' group
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=wheel
#
# home network; allow all valid ciphers
network={
        ssid="home"
        scan_ssid=1
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
        psk="very secret passphrase"
}
#
# work network; use EAP-TLS with WPA; allow only CCMP and TKIP ciphers
network={
        ssid="work"
        scan_ssid=1
        key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
        pairwise=CCMP TKIP
        group=CCMP TKIP
        eap=TLS
        identity="user [at] example.com"
        ca_cert="/etc/cert/ca.pem"
        client_cert="/etc/cert/user.pem"
        private_key="/etc/cert/user.prv"
        private_key_passwd="password"
}
```

Here's how to find a tag with a given value and print the value of some other tag using a standard UNIX tool:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"") }
/^network[[:space:]]*=/ {
    inNw = 1
    next
}
inNw {
    if ( /^[[:alnum:]_]+[[:space:]]*=/ ) {
        tag = val = $0
        sub(/[[:space:]]*=.*/,"",tag)
        sub(/[^=]+=[[:space:]]*/,"",val)
        f[tag] = val
    }
    else if ( /^}/ ) {
        if ( ( f[fndTag] == fndVal ) ||
             ( f[fndTag] == "\"" fndVal "\"" ) ) {
            print f[prtTag]
        }
        delete f
        inNw = 0
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -v fndTag='ssid' -v fndVal='home' -v prtTag='psk' -f tst.awk file
"very secret passphrase"

$ awk -v fndTag='ssid' -v fndVal='work' -v prtTag='key_mgmt' -f tst.awk file
WPA-EAP

$ awk -v fndTag='key_mgmt' -v fndVal='WPA-EAP' -v prtTag='identity' -f tst.awk file
"user [at] example.com"
```

The above will work using any awk in any shell on any UNIX box.

Comment: Exactly copied your files and example commands. I am getting no output. mawk 1.3.3

Comment: @dwjbosman that is a prehistoric version of mawk. If it doesn't work with the above then it doesn't conform to the current POSIX standard. Get a new version of awk, preferably gawk. If you can't do that then the most likely issue is mawkosaurus not understanding POSIX character classes so you could try changing `[[:alnum:]_]` to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` and `[[:space:]]` to `[ \t]` everywhere they occur in the script. You may even need to use a literal tab char instead of the escape sequence `\t`.

Comment: I just checked and mawk 1.3.3 is from 2003!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following `sed`:

```
ssid=12345678
sed -n '/ssid="'$ssid'"/{N;s/.*psk="\([^"]*\).*/\1/p}'
```

It will extract `87654321`.

Comment: thanks, but your solution will extract password from first record in file, i need extract certain password when i know ssid